# Artist data only save to database but not logged in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I am new in magento. We have artist concept in my site.

I want that when an artist register, data will save to database  but it will not be logged in.

By default data is saved to database and it will go to dashboard page but i want when an artist will do register then data will save to database but it will not login and redirect to same page.

I tried a lot but unable to stop the login concept only redirecting to same page but login functionalitily is still working using this condition

AccountController.php

```
if($data['artists']=='art'){            
     $successUrl = $this->_getUrl('artistregister/index/index', array('_secure' => true));
 }
else{
     $successUrl = $this->_getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure' => true));
}




protected function _successProcessRegistration(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer)
    {
        $session = $this->_getSession();
        if ($customer->isConfirmationRequired()) {
            /** @var $app Mage_Core_Model_App */
            $app = $this->_getApp();
            /** @var $store  Mage_Core_Model_Store*/
            $store = $app->getStore();
            $customer->sendNewAccountEmail(
                'confirmation',
                $session->getBeforeAuthUrl(),
                $store->getId()
            );
            $customerHelper = $this->_getHelper('customer');
            $session->addSuccess($this->__('Account confirmation is required. Please, check your email for the confirmation link. To resend the confirmation email please <a href="%s">click here</a>.',
                $customerHelper->getEmailConfirmationUrl($customer->getEmail())));
            $url = $this->_getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure' => true));
        } else {
            $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
            $url = $this->_welcomeCustomer($customer);
        }
        $this->_redirectSuccess($url);
        return $this;
    }
```

if anyone knows this, please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: can you post your save action here where artist data is saving in controller?

Comment: I updated the code please see above

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put condition in function `_successProcessRegistration`

In this function customer is logged in session by function

```
$session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
$url = $this->_welcomeCustomer($customer);
```

You can put condition for your artist here and change the URL as per your requirement.

Comment: can you tell me what will be the condition i will write because when i am writing this if($data['artists']!='art'){ 
          
   }else{  $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
            $url = $this->_welcomeCustomer($customer);}.................it is not working

Comment: I updated the code function _successProcessRegistration please see above

Comment: ya i have done now it is working fine but the problem is when i click on register button it is redirecting to home page......please suggest